# Calculate the characteristic function $\varphi_W$ of W

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions, density-function

> $p(x)=xe^{-x}$ for $x\geq 0$ or $0$ otherwise.

I tried to substitute  $e^{-x}$ but then i found there is still a $x$ in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\phi_W(t)=\langle e^{\mathrm{i}tx}\rangle=\int_0^\infty dx\ x e^{-x}e^{\mathrm{i}tx}=-\mathrm{i}\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^\infty dx\ e^{-(1-\mathrm{i}t)x}=-\mathrm{i}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{1-\mathrm{i}t}=\frac{1}{(1-\mathrm{i}t)^2}\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you and how do you find pdf of X+Y, where X and Y are independent exponential r.v.s,  each with parameter 1.

Comment: @user164945, please post another question. And if my answer was what you were looking for, don't forget to accept it. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Forgot about that :P   Hmm it's related question tho, if you could edit and answer it, I would be really appreciated.

Comment: You haven't accepted, just upvoted ;-) Will see what I can do...

Comment: Let $Z=X+Y$. Then
$$
p(z)=\int_0^\infty dx\int_0^\infty dy e^{-x-y}\delta(z-(x+y))=\int_0^z dx\ e^{-x}e^{-(z-x)}=z e^{-z}\ ,\mathrm{for}\quad z\geq 0\ .
$$

Comment: Hmm how to accept this, i thought upvote is to accept, oh my god. Never knew this for so long.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3411#3411

Comment: wow one question learnt 3 things Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome ;-)

Comment: I just posted another similar question, if you are here please help :P